# pandas: calculate diffs between rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{ "state": "CA", "total":2, "week": 10 },{ "state": "UT", "total": 7, "week": 10 },{ "state": "CA", "total": 14, "week": 11 },{ "state": "UT", "total":18, "week": 11 },{ "state": "CA", "total": 21, "week": 12 },{ "state": "UT", "total": 30, "week": 12 }])
```

The `total` field is cumulative, and I want to get the diffs by week. So I want to end up with this:

```
state,total,week,diff
CA,2,10,NaN
UT,7,10,NaN
CA,14,11,12
UT,18,11,11
CA,21,12,7
UT,30,12,12
```

How do I get there from here? I could do this by looping over the rows, but I don't know where to start to do this in pandas.

Comment: Are there "gaps" between weeks? For example week 11, then week 13 etc?

Comment: is there also more than 2 states in the general case?

Comment: @jlb_gouveia absolutely :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('state')['total'].diff()
df
```

Out:

```
  state  total  week  diff
0    CA      2    10   NaN
1    UT      7    10   NaN
2    CA     14    11  12.0
3    UT     18    11  11.0
4    CA     21    12   7.0
5    UT     30    12  12.0
```

Since `pandas 0.24` you can use [`nullable int types`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) but it's not  commonly used

```
df['diff'] = df.groupby('state')['total'].diff().astype(pd.Int64Dtype())
df
```

Out:

```
  state  total  week  diff
0    CA      2    10  <NA>
1    UT      7    10  <NA>
2    CA     14    11    12
3    UT     18    11    11
4    CA     21    12     7
5    UT     30    12    12
```

Comment: Thanks. How does this command 'know' what order to diff in? I'm finding that in my real dataset, the order seems to be mixed up.

Comment: The order is the current order of your dataframe `row - (row + 1)`. This assumes `df.sort_values('week')` to work properly,

Comment: Thanks! I had to add an explicit sort.